# NHibernate column uniqueness and inheritance

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, mapping

Consider the mapping file below. Both classes have a different notion of what the businessId is, which the object model handles, but it is acceptable to store it as a plain string in one column. I also want them each to have the same relationship with the Allocations set, which is the main reason I want them mapped using inheritance.

While the odds of a business id for a Project being the same as an Account are remote today, it would be ideal if there were a way to make the combination of the businessId and discriminator both part of the natural-id. This is not allowed, maybe for some good reason that I am not seeing.

Can I improve this mapping in some obvious way?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<class name="ActivitySubject" table="ActivitySubjects" discriminator-value="BASE_CLASS">

<id name="Id" unsaved-value="0">
  <column name="ActivitySubjectId" />
  <generator class="hilo" />
</id>

<discriminator column="ActivitySubjectType" type="System.String" />

<natural-id mutable="true">
  <property name="BusinessId" length="25" not-null="true" />
</natural-id>

<property name="Description" length="75" not-null="true" />

<set access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="Allocations">
  <key foreign-key="Allocations_Resource_FK">
    <column name="ActivityId" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Allocation />
</set>

<subclass name="Account" discriminator-value="ACCOUNT" />

<subclass name="SProject" discriminator-value="PROJECT" />
```

Here is the way I finally got both columns to be part of the same unique index:

```
<discriminator type="System.String"  >
  <column name="ActivitySubjectType" unique-key="ActivitySubjectTypeBusinessId" />
</discriminator>

<property name="BusinessId" length="25" not-null="true" node="1" unique-key="ActivitySubjectTypeBusinessId"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use natural ids for primary keys. I would use a synthetic key, a database generated identity or a GUID for the primary key and add a unique constraint on the combination of BusinessId and ActivitySubjectType.

Comment: Hi Jamie. I guess the unique constraint on the combination of BusinessId & ActivityType solves the immediate problem - is that just a matter of adding [unique-key="fullname"] to each property? I don't see how GUIDs improve on that, but maybe I'm missing something. I am also sorely tempted to split up these tables and use ANY to impose the relationships I want. HAve you had any good or bad experiences using that? Cheers.

Comment: I can't add a unique-key to the discriminator. Can you show me how to make the combination of the two part of the same constraint?

Comment: Are you thinking that natural-id was the primary key? Am using hilo for primary keys, with natural-id for non-surrogate natural keys like social security, etc. This lets NHib do some cache optimizations besides reading nicely, IMO. Not sure why NHib doesn't seem to want the discriminator to participate as part of a unique constraint tho.

Comment: I was thinking that natural-id was the primary key. I didn't know that attribute existed. I would add the unique constraint to the database directly, I wouldn't try to map it for schema generation.

Comment: It turns out this is easy to do once you treat the apply the unique-key to the discriminator as a node! I put the revised working mapping at the end of my original post. Thanks for the assist!